# /_ah/admin (and /_ah/*) doesn't exist in Python GAE with virtualenv

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I used to use vagrant to run my GAE Python apps, but I wanted to tried with virtualenv.

Everything worked okay, but I can't access anything in /_ah/* - I would only need /_ah/admin and also /_ah/img, where uploaded images from the admin panel are located.

I checked my app.yaml and it has everything: the admin_redirect builtin is okay, and I also tried to include the admin_redirect .py manually.

This is the file, just in case:
http://pastebin.com/eV9yTegf
(I tried with threadsafe yes and no, also).

Can anybody help? I am totally stuck, I tried everything and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Could you change the two urls that you have that starts with /_ah/ to something else and try again?

Comment: Same behaviour. I only left the main application handler but it doesn't detect the /_ah/admin

Comment: Totally forgot that is running in a different port now.. :) check my answer..

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the latest version (1.8.0+) then the admin console is actually running in a different port. By default is running in `http://localhost:8000/` but you can change that by running the `dev_appserver.py` with the an option `--admin_port`.

Comment: Hi Lipis. Yes, if I use dev_appserver.py this is correct. But I am running it with `manage.py runserver`. Is there a way to achieve the same with that?